# What is Index exceeds matrix dimensions error in matlab?

Tags: matlab

What is this error?

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>   Error in evalution (line 5)
>    binTempX(i,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])=parentXY(i,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);

```
function [tempX_Y_FXY] = evalution(parentXY,fXY)

for i=1:6

     binTempX(i,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])=parentXY(i,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]); 

    binTempY(i,[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],8)=parentXY(i,[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]);

    decTempX=bin2dec(binTempX(i,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]));
    decTempY=bin2dec(binTempY(i,[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]));

    tempX_Y_FXY(i,1)=decTempX;
    tempX_Y_FXY(i,2)=decTempY;

    tempX_Y_FXY(i,3)=fXY(decTempX,decTempY);

end

 tempX_Y_FXY=sortrows(tempX_Y_FXY,3);


 end
```

Comment: The error is very descriptive. It says that the indices you used for either `binTempX` or `parentXY` exceed the dimensions of that matrix. So you should probably check those two variables and make sure they're the size you expect them to be in your code. Also, please format the code properly in your question. All you have to do is select it and hit `ctrl-k`.

Answer (score 0):

```
binTempX(i,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])=parentXY(i,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]); 

%%% ------- what is this 8 doing here???
binTempY(i,[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],**8**)=parentXY(i,[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]);

decTempX=bin2dec(binTempX(i,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]));
decTempY=bin2dec(binTempY(i,[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]));

tempX_Y_FXY(i,1)=decTempX;
tempX_Y_FXY(i,2)=decTempY;

tempX_Y_FXY(i,3)=fXY(decTempX,decTempY);
```

Change this to:

```
binTempX(i,1:8)=parentXY(i,1:8); 

% removed the 8, because I think it is typo??
binTempY(i,9:16)=parentXY(i,9:16);

decTempX=bin2dec(binTempX(i,1:8));
decTempY=bin2dec(binTempY(i,9:16));

tempX_Y_FXY(i,1)=decTempX;
tempX_Y_FXY(i,2)=decTempY;

tempX_Y_FXY(i,3)=fXY(decTempX,decTempY);
```

if you want to select/assign multiple consecutive columns use the 1:8 notation for example. Both should work but in my opinion the second is clearer and easier to maintain.

And like beaker said, check the sizes of your matrices, does the matrices you use have at least 6 rows and 16 columns?

Comment: If this resolved your error, it would be nice to vote it up.